# Actionscript 3: How to detect when a button isn't pressed in time?

Tags: actionscript-3

Okay, this is another question for the game I am making. I am putting together a second level, where you need to press a long series of keys at the right time. Pressing them too early or too late results in failure. What I need to know is how to detect when a key ISN'T pressed, when it should have been. This is what I have so far:

```
var count3:Number = 23;
var myTimer3:Timer = new Timer(1000, count3);
var timeLeft3:Number = count3;
var buttonPressed:Boolean = false;
var btnCounter:Number = 2;
var btnTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000, btnCounter);

myTimer3.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countdown3);
myTimer3.start();
btnTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, btnCountdown);

btn1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonPress);

btn1.visible = false;
btn2.visible = false;
btn3.visible = false;
btn4.visible = false;
btn5.visible = false;
btn6.visible = false;
btn7.visible = false;
btn8.visible = false;
btn9.visible = false;

function countdown3(event:TimerEvent): void {

    if (((count3)-myTimer3.currentCount)==20) {
        btn1.visible = true;
        btnTimer.start();
    } else if (((count3)-myTimer3.currentCount)==19) {
        btn1.visible = true;
    } else {
        btn1.visible = false;
    }
}

function btnCountdown(event:TimerEvent):void {
    if (((btnCounter)-btnTimer.currentCount)==0) {
        if (buttonPressed = true) {
            btnTimer.stop();
        } else {
            gotoAndStop(2);
        }
    }
}

function buttonPress (event:MouseEvent): void {
    buttonPressed = true;
}
```

For some reason, it won't do anything when btnCounter hits 0. If someone could help me sort this out, that would be awesome. Thanks.

N.B. This is a personal project, I am just learning actionscript

Comment: no code and a deadline and asking for 'somebody' to do the job. Voted down. This doesn't belong here.

Comment: I am not asking for it to be done for me. I'm asking for help figuring it out. The game is for my studies, not a job. I didnt have the time to start coding the timers, as I needed to get to an appointment.

Comment: @David You can edit the question and you can ask people to vote to reopen it. If you add a code sample that shows what you did so far to solve it, people will retract their close votes.

Answer (score 0):

Start a timer for the time duration when the button is supposed to be pressed (for example, if the button must be pressed within 2 seconds, set the timer's interval to 2 seconds).

Then create a global `Boolean` variable (or class member variable, however your scene is set up) and set it to `false` initially. When the button is pressed, set this variable to `true` and disable the timer.

If the timer fires and this variable is `false`, it means that it hasn't been disabled by the button so the user didn't click the button within 2 seconds.

Don't use terribly short times - timers are not very accurate and processor speed may have an effect on their duration. (Human reaction times aside.)

Comment: Great, thankyou. I will try and get this sorted as soon as I can get to my computer.

Comment: I cant upvote yet. But it was helpful, although it doesnt seem to work properly. Likely a syntax error that doesnt trigger anything.

Comment: @David That's ok. If you have problems with the implementation, post it as another SO question (make sure you clearly state what's wrong and only post the minimal code needed to reproduce it).